# Search by File names in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, replace, file-search

I want to search for file names ending with 'E'  and having file extension as .h in visual studio 2013. I know there is ctrl+shift+F dialog but it doesn't search for file names. Similarly ctrl+, dumps everything even file contents. I just want to search for file names. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Files in the solution from within the IDE? The solution explorer has a search box at the top ... for an external tool install AgentRansack.

Comment: But how do I search for file names ending with 'E' from that solution box? I have tried that too

Comment: Can't you just just enter `E.h`

Comment: Thanks Alex K., it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Search Solution Explorer. **Shortcut - Ctrl + ;**

This is a small field on top of the Solution Explorer.

Type the following in the field: ***E.h.**

Needless to say * acts as a wildcard character matching 0 or more characters before E & the file would have an extension .h.

Comment: I just checked & found entering E.h would also suffice. In fact entering E.h as a search string also highlights the matching string in the filenames of the solution in the solution explorer.